# Time before - Is my usage mean the intended meaning?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I wrote this sentence  -

> Today what is possible thanks to advancement of technology was only real in sci-fi texts times before.

What I want to mean is that "these technological advanced is real today, but was not real sometimes back"

I know "sometimes back" is not sounding good, so I tried to use "time before". I guess you know what I want to mean. I really have no word to express this. Please help.

Comment: You could use "in the past", "in past times", "just a few years ago", ...

Comment: Just now found out "earlier". What about that?

Comment: No, *earlier* is not the right word.  "just a few years ago" as Photon says, is probably the best choice.

Comment: I also agree, but I didn't want to give hints of any time stamp. So that's why I though "earlier" might be the other option.

Comment: I'd also switch your placement of *real* and *possible*:  *What is real today, thanks to advancements in technology, was only possible in sci-fi stories[books] just a few years ago.*

Answer (score 2):

> Today what is possible thanks to advancement of technology was only real in sci-fi texts times before. (*)

You could replace "times before with "in the past", "in past times", or "just a few years ago".

You could also move things around and say something like

> What is possible today thanks to advancements of technology was **previously** only real in science fiction.

I also made a couple of other changes:

- we say "the advancement of technology" or "advancements in technology", but not "advancement of technology" without the article.
- "sci-fi" is considered somewhat derogatory (at least by sci-fi fans).
- "texts" was an unnecessary restriction---didn't sci-fi films also show some of those impossible things?
- "Today what is possible..." sounds clumsy, although I can't say for sure why. Probably it's a preference to have a single phrase before the verb.

Comment: One might say "*sci-fi* is considered somewhat derogatory (at least by SF fans)" ;-)

Comment: @snailplane, wouldn't that kinda ruin the joke?